# PHP different value of a variable if the field is empty

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
$sn_inlocuit = $_POST['sn_inlocuit'];
$sn_def = $_POST['sn_def'];
        
if(empty($sn_inlocuit) && empty($sn_def))
{
    $ref_echip = "NULL";
} else {
    $ref_echip = rand('100000000','999999999');
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO rapoarte (sn,sn_2,ref_echip) VALUES ('$sn','$sn_2','$ref_echip')";
```

I have the two fields above which if they are empty I want nothing to be entered in the column of the MYSQL table and if they are not empty, a random number is generated for me and it is entered in the respective column.

The problem is that even if the field is empty, it inserts my random number.

I just attached a piece of code with this condition (if) that doesn't work for me.

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

EDIT:
I forgot to specify and I missed this, both of my input fields are "multiple input fields" with "Add field button".

```
<input type="text" placeholder="S/N" name="sn_inlocuit[]">
<input type="text" placeholder="S/N" name="sn_def[]">
```

Var_dump gave me this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }
```

So in this situation, with multiple input fields how I can do what I want with the If(empty) statement?

Comment: Are you sure the input is "empty" as defined by PHP? Using an empty string for both values, the code given works fine: https://3v4l.org/P3tV8

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but have you dumped the two vars you're checking to verify that they're truly as empty as you think they are? (Ah, I see someone else already asked that. I meant _great_ question @IMSoP)

Comment: Rule 1 of debugging. Dump the data that is doing something funny. Try a `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: @IMSoP field are empty, what can I do more then that?

Comment: @B__ I expressed myself wrong, the condition is that if both of the fields are empty

Comment: @Thebeatmaker What do you mean by "empty"? How are you checking that? Have you tried dumping `$_POST` as RiggsFolly suggested? Because clearly PHP thinks they are _not_ empty, and I'm willing to bet a large sum of money that it's not just randomly saying so.

Comment: @IMSoP Ok, I tried this what RiggsFolly suggested. I forgot to mention and with this method I realized that I did not specify something, both of my input fields are "multiple input fields" with "Add field button".  Var_dump gave me this: `array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }`  So in this situation, with multiple input fields how I can do what I want with the If(empty) statement?

Comment: That's a really important difference. You should [edit] your question to reflect that.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I edited, I apologize for not specifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering those `$_POST` values are arrays rather than strings, I think using `array_filter` rather than `empty` will work in most cases.

```
if (!array_filter($sn_inlocuit) && !array_filter($sn_def))
```

As far as other cases, there are some values that could be entered that will evaluate to false and be filtered out by `array_filter`, e.g. "0", so you may need a more specific filter function if you don't want that to happen. You may also want to trim the values in the arrays before checking them to avoid whitespace-only values which will *not* be filtered out by `array_filter`, unless you want those to be considered as actual values.

```
$sn_inlocuit = array_map('trim', $_POST['sn_inlocuit']);
$sn_def = array_map('trim', $_POST['sn_def']);
```

Comment: I implemented as you suggested and it works! Thanks to everyone for their help!

Answer (score -1):

for if statement:

> $ref_echip = "NULL";

you will set the variable into string. if you mean to set it into boolean, you can use this instead:

> $ref_echip = NULL;

and you can put your SQL command to else statement so the SQL command will run while the variable $sn_inlocuit and $sn_def is not empty

Comment: This isn't relevant to the issue being asked about. And also it's not good advice for when constructing the SQL string in the way the OP is doing. Overall, this answer doesn't make much sense, unfortunately.